# Tokenising binary data in java

Tags: java, binary

I am writing some code to handle a stream of binary data. It is received in chunks represented by byte arrays. Combined, the byte arrays represent sequential stream of messages, each of which ends with the same constant terminator value (0xff in my case). However, the terminator value can appear at any point in any given chunk of data. A single chunk can contain part of a message, multiple messages and anything in between.

Here is a small sampling of what data handled by this might look like:

```
[0x00, 0x0a, 0xff, 0x01]
[0x01, 0x01]
[0xff, 0x01, 0xff]
```

This data should be converted into these messages:

```
[0x00, 0x0a, 0xff]
[0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xff]
[0x01, 0xff]
```

I have written a small class to handle this. It has a method to add some data in byte array format, which is then placed in a buffer array. When the terminator character is encountered, the byte array is cleared and the complete message is placed in a message queue, which can be accessed using hasNext() and next() methods (similar to an iterator).

This solution works fine, but as I finished it, I realized that there might already be some stable, performant and tested code in an established library that I could be using instead.

So my question is - do you know of a utility library that would have such a class, or maybe there is something in the standard Java 6 library that can do this already?

Comment: Byte array searching and manipulation is something which I sometimes miss in Java. One can use a buffered byte stream child class which can do a per byte test for `0xff`. In some cases one can utilise a pipeline: see [PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a framework as a custom parser is simple enough.

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{
        0x00, 0x0a, (byte) 0xff,
        0x01, 0x01, 0x01, (byte) 0xff,
        0x01, (byte) 0xff});

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (int b; (b = in.read()) >= 0; ) {
    baos.write(b);
    if (b == 0xff) {
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }
}
```

prints as `(byte) 0xFF == -1`

```
[0, 10, -1]
[1, 1, 1, -1]
[1, -1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks promising and certainly more elegant than what I have, but the data I have comes in as separate byte arrays, not as one byte array like in the example you have given.

Comment: Where does it come from as `byte[]`? Are you reading from a device or network?

Comment: It is actually read from a serial port, so the data looks like a series of byte arrays

Comment: So when you read from the serial device it returns a new `byte[]` each time? You cannot read it like an InputStream?

Comment: The data does come from an InputStream. I wasn't looking at this the right way. The solution you have given actually works brilliantly for what I need to do. Thanks!